# SFINAE for constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

Before closing this as a duplicate (since there are several questions like this which did actually explain how to achieve the solution - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603353/sfinae-on-constructors-works-in-vc2017-but-not-in-clang-gcc), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978556/trouble-using-sfinae-to-switch-constructors)), I did go through the similar questions, but after doing the same I still get hit by the `'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration`. So here is my example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace std
{
    
template<typename>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};

}

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename ... Arguments>
    Foo(Arguments&& ... arguments, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor without shared_ptr\n";
    }
    
    template<typename ... Arguments>
    Foo(Arguments&& ... arguments, std::enable_if_t<std::is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor with shared_ptr\n";
    }

    T value_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Foo<int> a;
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<int>> b;
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1f244ca339c464b) is the link to this example on coliru. What I want to achieve is being able to initialise `value_` with make shared when `T` is `std::shared_ptr`. The other questions show that moving the `std::enable_if` deduction to function parameters work, but not in my case. Am I missing/overlooked something in the examples?

Comment: Once you have fixed `T` by the **class**, `std::enable_if_t<std::is_shared_ptr<T>::value>*` would be a hard failure (it is not substitution of template argument of the function).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ahh, yeah both examples have a `bool`  template type, not an actual `typename`. So in this case I cannot achieve the result?

Comment: As an aside, adding declarations to namespace `std` produces undefined behavior. `is_shared_ptr` should be in your own namespace.

Comment: Possibly something like `typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<cond_v<U>>* = 0>`

Comment: Adding and additional "artificial" type template parameter set to `T` by default and applying SFINAE to this parameter should work. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/er66cnT7r. One of many relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30953248/580083.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah just thought of that myself and tried it - it works, but seems weird that I need to do this kind of looping around. If you post this as an answer I'll happily accept that.

Comment: in c++20 `requires` allow simpler syntax :-)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes I know, this was just a quick sample.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I saw how `requires` would fix that while brosing SO, but I'm stuck with msvc 2017 (and as far as I googled msvc has `requires` only in 2022).